# doesnotrecognizeselector exception

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Using NSXMLParser

why does this line of code cause an exception:

```
ushort crash = [[attributeDict objectForKey:@"a"] unsignedShortValue];
```

The value in the xml file is "0"

if I use integerValue it works

what is happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you looked at the object throwing the exception, you would see it's something that doesn't have an unsignedShortValue method — I think NSString in this case.